# using match with jquery but consider hyphen as part of the word

Tags: jquery

My string `See Good-by`

I have this which matches all the words in the string

```
var result = $(this).text().match(/\b(\w+)\b/gi);
```

but it is considering the `-` as not part of the word. Is it possible to consider hyphens as part of the word as long as there is no space between the hyphen and the words next to it?

Here is my full code

```
$('.definition').each( function(p) {
    var c = '';
    var result = $(this).text().match(/\b[\w-]+\b/g);
    $.each(result, function(i) {
        if (result[i] != '') {
            if ($.inArray(result[i].toLowerCase(), stopwords) === -1) {
                var link = ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + result[i].toLowerCase() + '/">' + result[i] + '</a>';
                c += link;
            } else {
                c += " "+result[i];
            }
        }
    })
    $(this).html(c);
})
```

**SOLVED**

I have a list of stop words in an array that I need to check with so they are not included as links. Here is the working code thanks too @Pranav C Balan

```
$('.definition').html(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\b[\w-]+\b/g, function(m){
        if ($.inArray(m.toLowerCase(), stopwords) === -1) {
            return ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + m.toLowerCase() + '/">' + m + '</a>';
        } else {
            return " "+m;
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to combine `-` with the word character. Although the `i` flag is completely unnecessary here since `\w` includes both small and capital letters.

```
var result = $(this).text().match(/\b[\w-]+\b/g);
```

```js
console.log(
  'See Good-by'.match(/\b[\w-]+\b/g)
)
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** I think you are overcomplicating the problem in the updated code. Instead of getting matched string and generating the string, generate the string using [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a callback.

```
$('.definition').each(function() {
  var result = $(this).text().replace(/\b[\w-]+\b/g, function(m){
    return ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + m.toLowerCase() + '/">' + m + '</a>';
  });
  // or
  // return $(this).text().replace(/\b[\w-]+\b/g, ' <a href="/dictionary/word/$&/">$&</a>');  
  $(this).html(result);
})
```

You can even reduce the above code using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method with a callback which iterates internally over the elements.

```
$('.definition').html(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/\b[\w-]+\b/g, function(m){
    return ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + m.toLowerCase() + '/">' + m + '</a>';
  });
  // or
  // return $(this).text().replace(/\b[\w-]+\b/g, ' <a href="/dictionary/word/$&/">$&</a>');
})
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** To avoid `stopwords` as in your code use the logic within the replace callback.

```
$('.definition').html(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/\b[\w-]+\b/g, function(m){
    return $.inArray(result[i].toLowerCase(), stopwords) === -1 ? ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + m.toLowerCase() + '/">' + m + '</a>' : m;
  });
})
```

or use it with the regex with help of [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
$('.definition').html(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(new RegExp('(?!(?:' + stopwords.join('|') + ')\\b)\\b[\\w-]+\\b', 'g'), function(m){
    return ' <a href="/dictionary/word/' + m.toLowerCase() + '/">';
  });
})
```

Comment: its working for this, but it is removing commas in another strings I just noticed. So if the string is like `this-thing, is , it` it changes it to `this-thing is it` and not keeping the commas or other special charcters like `:`, `;` and so on.

Comment: @CesarBielich : you need to include it in the character class(whatever symbols you need)

Comment: I attached my full code, I am converting words in a string to links

Comment: @CesarBielich : what's the expected o/p for string `this-thing, is , it` ?

Comment: `<a href="#">this-thing</a>, <a href="#">is</a>, <a href="#">it</a>`

Comment: its not working, now it does not add the links and removes everything but the letters so it's one long string with no spaces

Comment: works! except I have a list of stop words in an array I check for that I do not want included which is missing from your code, but I think I can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks man, You can see the code working in the definitions https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/dictionary/word/testing/

Comment: @CesarBielich : glad to help you :)